# Which is Better to Use?

Tags: american-english

I am wondering which is better to use- utilize or use? What do you guys think? Does it depend on what are you using the word for?

Answer (score 1):

"Utilize" tends to sound a bit pompous, so in almost any context "use" is more useful :) OTO, as the root of "utilization", "utilizable", etc, it may better express meaning in some contexts.

Even that utilization is a bit dubious, consider instead the usability of "usage".